# How to get and modify Xtend AST

Tags: eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, xtend

Hy all,

I would like to write an Eclipse plugin to process and modify the AST of the current xtend editor. How can I get the AST of the xtend editor?

Thanks!

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more what you want to do? did you have a look at Active Annotations? how shall the modification be invoked?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a plug-in to process the AST, as you can process it with an Active Annotation. That said it doesn't include the full expressions, but just the Java members. 
Hooking into the compiler via an (Eclipse) extension is not supported and not possible without AOP.